# Cannot get sambaSID from LDAP using Spring LDAP

Tags: java, ldap, samba, spring-ldap

I am trying to populate some samba values in my LDAP based on some user information.
Among other things, I have to create a 'sambaSID' for a user. 
It is composed of two values: the prefix which is the sambaSID of a sambaDomainName object and the suffix which is 1000 + (2* uid) oder the user.

I can see the sambaSID attribute from my sambaDomainName using ldapsearch like so:

```
ldapsearch -x  -D {adminUser} -W -H ldap://...:389 -b $base -s sub "sambaDomainName=TRON" sambaSID
```

the adminUser and base are correctly provided.

Now, if I try to do the same in Java using Spring LDAP, I see all the attributes *except* for the SambaSID. The same behaviour happens for a LDAP group object, from which I also need the SambaSID.

As I can read any other property, I believe there is something special about the SambaSID.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks in advance!
DodoFXP

Comment: Please post your code to show how you "try to do the same in Java using Spring LDAP".

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue:

I am using spring-ldap, creating a LdapContextSource, configuring it with a principal and password and then passing it to a LdapTemplate.

The LdapTemplate does not use .getReadWriteContext() which performs the authentication.
Hence, I was using anonymous access. When doing operation on the DirContext returned by getReadWriteContext() I get all attributes.

Plus, the authentication has been reenabled on the LDAP so anonymous shows even less attributes now.